# Ruby: collecting all arrays with matching elements from a 2d array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array that looks like

```
array = [["apples", 11], ["oranges", 3], ["bananas", 7], ["oranges", 4], ["apples", 6], ["oranges", 9]]
```

and I want to somehow collect all matching strings and sum the integers in the associated arrays.
For example I would like the output to look like

```
totals_array = [["apples", 17], ["oranges", 16], ["bananas", 7]]
```

I'm not restrained in a way to do this but can't think of a neat way to do it. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like below:

```
array = [["apples", 11], ["oranges", 3], ["bananas", 7], ["oranges", 4], ["apples", 6], ["oranges", 9]]

totals_array = array.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |h, s| h[s[0]] += s[1]; h }.to_a
```

or

```
totals_array = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(name,count),hash| hash[name] += count }.to_a
```

Comment: `each_with_object` I like for this.. :-)

Comment: Would you like `array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(name,count),hash| hash[name] += count }.to_a` ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd do:

```
array.group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k,v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
# => [["apples", 17], ["oranges", 16], ["bananas", 7]]
```

Comment: @user70434 Go with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22684081/2767755).. Mine is slower..

Answer (score -1):

I would like to do this:--

```
array.map{|a| [a[0], array.inject(0){|sum, e| e[0] == a[0] ? 
sum + e[1] : sum}]}.uniq
#=>[["apples", 17], ["oranges", 16], ["bananas", 7]]
```